# Iterative Computation in a Window with Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, iteration, spark-streaming, windowing

I am trying to do an analysis of iterative stream processing with Apache Spark streaming. The objective is to create a window and do a computation on the windowed elements. In Apache Flink or Apache Storm, the APIs are provided to do this. For instance in Apache Storm, a function provides a list of items belonging to a specific window. In Apache Flink, an iterator of the items belonging to the window is contained. But is there such capability with Spark Streaming? I tried the API docs and I couldn't find a clear answer. The objective is that I need to have access to all the elements belonging to a given window and do a computation on those items. I need to run a finite loop on that list of items. Is this possible with Apache Spark streaming?

I have tried adding a window and then map function and creating an iteration within the driver and run the map and process functions within the loop. But this gives a totally different answer.

```scala
for(i <- 1 to iterations) {

      newWStream = trainStream.map(s => {
      //mapping definition        
      })

      val newW: DStream[ArrayBuffer[Double]] = newWStream
        .reduce((w1, w2) => {
         //reduce after the mapping 
        })


      newW.foreachRDD((rdd, time) => {
         // do final test
         // broadcast the reduced value after evaluating it
      })

}
```

This is the closest, that I can get to it. But the real objective is not to do a mapping per element, but do something like below.

```scala
stream.window().windowfunction(new WindowFunction(List<T> windowElements){
// do iterative computation
})
```

Does Spark Streaming support this?

Comment: It looks like you are using DStream option of Spark Streaming. What version are you using ? You should use Structure Streaming: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations

Comment: @Vincent I am using 2.4.4 version. Yes, I use DStream. I also took a look at the APIs. Is there a way to support my requirement? I may have missed if there is one. Could you please point out?

Comment: You should be able to do what you want using DStream, it just might be easier using Structure Streaming. Anyway, what kind of "iterative computation" are you looking for, because it's kind of the opposite of what Spark is for

Comment: The main issue is there is no access to a window. Specifically, no window function is available with Spark. That makes life difficult. I want to do an iterative computation for a window and then synchronize the calculated value globally.